# If the set of all polynomials is infinite-dimensional, then why is the set of all functions on [a,b] also infinite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

So it's known that the set of all polynomials is infinite-dimensional.  However, if $U[a,b]$ is the set of all functions defined on [a,b], then how would I show that U[a,b] is also infinite-dimensional?

Comment: Wouldn't the polynomials interpreted as functions restricted to $[a,b]$ be an infinite dimensional subspace of $U[a,b]$?

Comment: So then the set of functions could then be proved to be infinite-dimensional in the same way that the set of all polynomials would be?

Comment: Once you have proved that a subspace is infinite dimensional it directly follows that the original vector space is infinite dimensional as well. You can prove this in general using the contrapositive form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did it, consider the polynomial functions on [a,b], i.e.,

Consider the Map $F:\mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow U[a,b]$ that sends the polynomial g(x) into the polinomial map $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, trivially F is linear and injective because if two polinomial functions agree on an interval they come from the same polynomial. This proves you that you can embed an infinite dimensional space into $U[a,b]$, i.e., $U[a,b]$ has infinitely many linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The functions $1_{\{x\}}$ $(a\leq x\leq b)$ are obviously linearly independent, and there is an infinity of them.